# How to implement a custom gtk::TreeModel in rust?

Tags: rust, gtk4

I am creating a gtk4 + rust based application that will show a TreeView widget to display parent/child relationships. I have used the TreeStore to populate the TreeView but have not been able to find examples of using a custom TreeModel to populate the TreeView.

Does anybody know how or have some examples showing how?